# Pass values from AppComponent to any routed component

Tags: typescript, angular12

Working currently on Angular 12, I am trying to send data from **AppComponent** to any routed component, say **HomeComponent**.
**HomeSelector** (who calls **HomeComponent**) is routed inside **AppRoutingModule** as follows:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { Page404Component } from './page404/page404.component';

import { HomeSelector } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeSelector },
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home' },
  { path: '**', component: Page404Component }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Below is my **AppComponent**, from where I am trying to pass values **nomeSessao** and **ultimaAtualizacaoSessao** to **HomeComponent**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { SsoAttributesResponse } from './tipos/response/sso-attributes-response';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  nomeSessao: string | null;
  ultimaAtualizacaoSessao: string | null;
  
  constructor(private appService: AppService) {
    this.nomeSessao = localStorage.getItem('sn');
    this.ultimaAtualizacaoSessao = localStorage.getItem('ultAtu');
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('localStorage.getItem(\'sn\') = ' + localStorage.getItem('sn'));
    if (localStorage.getItem('sn') === null) {
      this.appService.consultarAtributosSessao().subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        let response = new SsoAttributesResponse(res);
        localStorage.setItem('sn', response.getAttributes('sn')[0]);
        localStorage.setItem('ultAtu', response.getAttributes('ultAtu')[0]);
        this.nomeSessao = localStorage.getItem('sn');
        this.ultimaAtualizacaoSessao = localStorage.getItem('ultAtu');
      });
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.nomeSessao = null;
    this.ultimaAtualizacaoSessao = null;
    localStorage.clear;
  }
}
```

And below is **HomeComponent**, where I am trying to dynamically receive values from **AppComponent**:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, SimpleChanges, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() nome: string | null;
  @Input() ultimaAtualizacao: string | null;

  constructor() {
    this.nome = null;
    this.ultimaAtualizacao = null;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-selector',
  template:
    `<app-home [nome]="nomeCompleto" [ultimaAtualizacao]="ultimaAtualizacao"></app-home>`
})
export class HomeSelector {
  nomeCompleto: string | null = null;
  ultimaAtualizacao: string | null = null;
  
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.nomeCompleto = this.appService.nome;
    this.ultimaAtualizacao = this.appService.ultimaAtualizacao;
    console.log(changes);
  }
}
```

As far as I can get, values on **nome** and **ultimaAtualizacao** are not changing. What did I miss here?

Answer (score 0):

If the data is in your local storage you can just get it from there again.

However, if you are routing somewhere and expect to get data, the route will need some identifier. If people go to 'yourpage.com/home' directly, how would that data be fetched without some id?

Another way is to work with a data service. Are you trying to get userdata somehow? In that case you want some sort of AuthenticationService. So that when people aren't authenticated, they are redirected to a login. Their data and name gets stored in this service. You can then access this data anywhere in the application.

Comment: Unfortunately, an authentication service already exists (called by _this.appService.consultarAtributosSessao()_ ), but because of my company rules, that shall be called only once (e.g. when starting a session). Also, the login validation service is called already by Nginx. Also, I ask for how to reflect updates as soon as the fields **nome** and **ultimaAtualizacao** changes, that is not working now.

Comment: I don't know the context on what you are trying to do just from what is in your question. But you need an observable of some sort to react to 'changes'. You can't do this via local storage, unless you would regularly check if the value has changed, but that is not a good practice. What you want is to store the value 'nome' in some (data)service. Push it to some Subject and get it as an observable from that service wherever you need in the application.